# Detect Walking/Movement in Ionic App

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I would like to know if there is any possibility of detecting if a person is walking or not in an Ionic App.

To be specific, I would only want to know whether there is some activity or not, and not specifics like number of steps etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should have a look at this plugin :
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device-motion

Or there is an angular plugin that should work with ionic : http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/deviceMotion/

Maybe you could use the watchAcceleration function?

Comment: What about directions? @sriram

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to solve this? The Android Activity Recognition api seems to be what you're looking for, but I'd love to know if there's a ionic way to do it (so it works on ios also).

Answer (score -4):

You can detect these activities:

IN_VEHICLE  The device is in a vehicle, such as a car.
ON_BICYCLE  The device is on a bicycle.
ON_FOOT The device is on a user who is walking or running.
RUNNING The device is on a user who is running.
STILL   The device is still (not moving).
TILTING The device angle relative to gravity changed significantly.
UNKNOWN Unable to detect the current activity.
WALKING The device is on a user who is walking.

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/DetectedActivity.html

Comment: I am looking for  Ionic specific solution. This looks like Native android way of doing it.

Comment: ah ok, then no idea. You can create a plugin but that should be a native way

Comment: At least if someone says its not possible(definitively) , I will move on to native way of doing it. Looks like Native way of doing it is quite easy.

Comment: And the native way of doing is? It will be interesting to know if there is something already that fine and tunned to let you know that in an abstract way. On the other hand, the Ionic way to do it is then translated to the cordova way of do it, so as the others says, you could use the accelerometer cordova plugin and program our awesome code to decide when you have an activity or not.